# Variable Creation methods in C++

Tags: c++, vector

Hey guys I'm trying to write a method to create vectors named y_i where i starts at 1 and ends at a variable names rows for entering a matrix. 
I'm trying to write it so that it dynamically adds enough vectors to this code. Vectors of the form vector y_1, vector y_2 etc etc.

Code is below. My questions are am I doing this right? do I need a struct? A class? Help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int i, rows;
vector<vector< double > >matrix;
void VectorCreation(int rows)
{
    for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
    {
        new vector<double>;
    }
}
int main()
{
    cin >> rows;
    VectorCreation(rows);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't start with global variables, and most of the time you don't need to use `new` in modern C++ (plus, you don't *do anything* with that!).

Comment: _`new vector<double>;`_ this line makes absolutely no sense. You allocate a `vector<double>` (which you shouldn't anyway), and discard the result.

Comment: Oy.... where to start? Don't use `new` *unless you know what you are doing*. Don't use global variables *unless you know what you are doing*. Don't try to trial&error C++. [Get a good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242). ;-) That being said, what you're looking for is [documentation](http://www.cppreference.com)...

Answer (score 1):

You currently allocate a `std::vector` on the heap with `new` but don't assign it to anything so the data allocated is forever lost.

I wouldn't advice using `new` for this but just using stack allocation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int rows;
vector<vector< double > >matrix;
void VectorCreation(int rows)
{
  matrix.resize(rows);
}
int main()
{
    cin >> rows;
    VectorCreation(rows);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And this is why i asked for help. Being relative new to C++ and all. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First off

```
void VectorCreation(int rows)
{
    for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++)
    {
        new vector<double>;
    }
}
```

Is doing nothing but creating a memory leak as you are creating new vectors and then letting the pointers to them go out of scope so the memory is no longer accessible but being used.

Secondly if you want to create a 2d vector you would use:

```
std::vector<std::vector<type>> vector_name(num_rows, std::vector<type>(num_cols, default_value));
```

Comment: And how to display an element of a 2d vector?

Comment: @ChrisJabbour [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937550/two-dimensional-vector-printing) is an example of how to print 2d vector.