# Determine row size and column size in a multi-dimensional array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, size

How can I determine the **size** of a 2-Dimensional array in C++ when each row and column size may vary?

I'm trying to make a function called `Parser` that reads the array. So far, I have:

```
// Function:    Parser.
// Description: First, it reads the data in the array.
//              Then, it uses the data in the array.
void Parser (char ch[][]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof (ch) / sizeof (ch [0])); ++i) {
        // TO DO - Add content.
    }
}
```

Array `ch` can contain elements such as:

```
{
    {
        'v', 'o', 'i', 'd'
    },

    {
        'i', 'n', 't'
    },
}
```

*Is there a solution*?

Comment: You can't.  Use `std::vector<std::vector<char>>` instead,

Comment: You have basically three ways: 1) Don't use plain arrays but `std::array` or `std::vector`. 2) Pass sizes of array as function parameters. 3) End array with some special character, like `'\0'`.

Comment: @NO_NAME `std::array` does not support jagged arrays.

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<char>> arr = {{'v', 'o', 'i', 'd'},{'i', 'n', 't'}};` is what you want

Comment: Vector of vectors does a lot of dynamic memory allocations. But you can simply store variable-row(/column)-length 2D array into a plain 1D array. Look for CSR sparse matrix storage format to understand the concept. There is an additional array which stores offset for each row into the array of values. Then, you can find out the length of any row in _O(1)_. In your case, it might look like `std::vector<char> vals = {'v','o','i','d','i','n','t'};` and `std::vector<int> offsets = {0,4,7};`.

Comment: OK... Can anybody redirect me to a page explaining how to use the contents of the 2-Dimensional Vector (I.e vector <vector <char> >)?

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937550/two-dimensional-vector-printing

Comment: Thanks. It helped me.

Comment: This is a temporary message to the author of the post regarding this [suggested-edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20066179). Do not edit questions that are closed as they are forwarded to further review due to your edit. And do not convert a code snippet to html-css code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did was, I made `ch` a `vector`. I passed `ch`'s size to iterator `i` in the first `for` loop, then `ch[i]`'s size to iterator `j`.

---

The **new** code is:

```cpp
// Function:    Parser.
// Description: First, it reads the data in the vector.
//              Then, it uses the data in the vector.
void Parser (vector <vector <char>> ch) {
    for (int i = 0; i < ch.size (); ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ch[i].size (); ++j) {
            // TO DO - Add content.
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

There are Many ways

Use Templates:

```
template <typename T, size_t N, size_t M>
void Parser (T (&ch)[N][M])
{

}
```