# how do I print a vector of vector of bools

Tags: c++, vector

Here's what I tried

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using std::vector;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
const int n{5},s{9},arr[]{2,3,7,8,11};
vector<vector<bool>>dp;
void print(){
    for(auto &x :dp){
        for(bool y:x){
            cout<<y<<' ';
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
int main(){
print();
}
```

The program crashes with nothing being printed.
What is the correct way to do it. Also what does auto stand for in this case.

Comment: The shown code in this question does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. This question must be [edit]ed to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two-dimensional vector printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26937550/two-dimensional-vector-printing)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I'm sorry, I added the whole code.

Comment: @LukaKostic answers to this question do not state what auto stands for.

Comment: Plenty of other questions answer what 'auto' is.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the shown code, except that the vector is empty so there's nothing to print. Why exactly do you believe there's anything in this vector that should be printed? Which part of the shown code you believe populates the vector with some values?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes, I get it. I apologize for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the correct way to do it.

Your example program is a correct way.

> The program crashes

It shouldn't. Either you are mistaken, or there is something wrong with your system.

> ... with nothing being printed.

This makes sense. You are printing a vector of vector of bool that is empty. There is nothing to print.